# What do I do with serialized data from Django in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, django, serialization

I have a web backend that provides me the info in a json format. For example:
[image: the info show in the image],, What I'd like to know is, using Javascript, how can I taje advantage of such data to create the frontend? Typically, I would use return reder from Django, but in this case I am already returning the serialized data! Should I do a fetch from JavaScript? Please any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you have to use [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/language/) to show that data, you can access the data as context instead of making an extra request to Django in javascript.

```
context = {...} # include your data
return render(request, "example.html", context)
```